# Can't change the mouse cursor of a NSTextField

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nscursor, nstrackingarea

I'm trying to change the mouse cursor of a `NSTextField` in a window sheet, loaded from a NIB.

Following the documentation, I have subclassed `NSTextField` and implemented [`resetCursorRects`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsview_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/resetCursorRects).

```
- (void) resetCursorRects {
    [self addCursorRect:[self bounds] cursor:[NSCursor pointingHandCursor]];
}
```

This is never called. Not even after adding the following in the `NSWindowViewController`:

```
- (void) windowDidLoad {
    [self.window invalidateCursorRectsForView:self.linkTextField];
}
```

I also tried with a tracking area by adding the following in the `NSTextField` subclass:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib {
    NSTrackingArea* trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:self.bounds
                                                 options:(NSTrackingCursorUpdate | NSTrackingActiveAlways)
                                                   owner:self
                                                userInfo:nil];
    [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
}

- (void)cursorUpdate:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [[NSCursor pointingHandCursor] set];
}
```

Didn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I am having a similar issue.

Comment: @Jensen Nope. Are you trying something different?

Comment: Just managed to solove this by overriding the mouseMoved method in its superview.

Comment: @Jensen Why don't post it as an answer? I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 8):

[Clickable links with NSTextField](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=677713)

I got this working after subclassing `NSTextField` as mentioned :

```
- (void)resetCursorRects {
    [self addCursorRect:[self bounds] cursor:[NSCursor pointingHandCursor]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

NSTextView seems to be handling the cursor through its `-(void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent*)theEvent` method. Also, when the NSTextView becomes first responder, some private code in the RunLoop seems to force the cursor to the IBeamCursor without giving us a choice. Here is a subclass that works around those limitations :

```
@interface MyTextView : NSTextView {
    NSTrackingArea* area;
    BOOL mouseInside;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSTrackingArea* area;

@end


@implementation MyTextView

@synthesize area;

- (void)setArea:(NSTrackingArea *)newArea
{
    [newArea retain];
    if (area) {
        [self removeTrackingArea:area];
        [area release];
    }
    if (newArea) {
        [self addTrackingArea:newArea];
    }
    area = newArea;
}

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    NSRect rect = <insert the tracking rect where you want to have a special cursor>;
    self.area = [[[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:rect options:NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveWhenFirstResponder owner:self userInfo:nil] autorelease];
    NSEvent* ev = [NSApp currentEvent];
    if (NSPointInRect([self convertPoint:ev.locationInWindow fromView:nil], self.bounds)) {
        mouseInside = YES;
        // This is a workaround for the private call that resets the IBeamCursor
        [[NSCursor arrowCursor] performSelector:@selector(set) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
    }
}

- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    [super mouseEntered:theEvent];
    [[NSCursor arrowCursor] set];
    mouseInside = YES;
}

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    [super mouseExited:theEvent];
    mouseInside = NO;
}

- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    si (!mouseInside) {
        // We only forward the mouseMoved event when the mouse is outside the zone for which we control the cursor
        [super mouseMoved:theEvent];
    }
}

- (oneway void)dealloc
{
    [area release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the cursorUpdate method was called each time the cursor entered the tracking area, but the cursor was set back somewhere else, probably its superview.

I managed to solve it by overriding the mouseMoved method.

```
// In the textfield subclass:
- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [super mouseEntered:theEvent];
    self.isMouseIn = YES;
}

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [super mouseExited:theEvent];
    self.isMouseIn = NO;
}


//In the superview of the textfield:
- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    if (self.hoverButton.isMouseIn) {
        [[NSCursor pointingHandCursor] set];
    }
    [super mouseMoved:theEvent];
}
```

I overrided the mouseMoved method in my windowController class, but overriding the superview should work.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Swift version 2.0 of the answers above and made it available as a [GitHub sample project found here](https://github.com/dautermann/ChangeCursorColor).

And even though it's set for NSTextField, the concepts should work with anything that subclasses from `NSResponder` (which is where `mouseEntered` and `becomeFirstResponder` come from).

Here's the guts of the code I wrote:

```
import Cocoa

class CCTextField: NSTextField {

    var myColorCursor : NSCursor?

    var mouseIn : Bool = false

    var trackingArea : NSTrackingArea?

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        myColorCursor = NSCursor.init(image: NSImage(named:"heart")!, hotSpot: NSMakePoint(0.0, 0.0))
    }

    override func resetCursorRects() {
        if let colorCursor = myColorCursor {
            self.addCursorRect(self.bounds, cursor: colorCursor)
        }
    }

    override func mouseEntered(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseEntered(theEvent)
        self.mouseIn = true
    }

    override func mouseExited(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseExited(theEvent)
        self.mouseIn = false
    }

    override func mouseMoved(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        if self.mouseIn {
            myColorCursor?.set()
        }
        super.mouseMoved(theEvent)
    }

    func setArea(areaToSet: NSTrackingArea?)
    {
        if let formerArea = trackingArea {
            self.removeTrackingArea(formerArea)
        }

        if let newArea = areaToSet {
            self.addTrackingArea(newArea)
        }
        trackingArea = areaToSet
    }

    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        let rect = self.bounds
        let trackingArea = NSTrackingArea.init(rect: rect, options: [NSTrackingAreaOptions.MouseEnteredAndExited, NSTrackingAreaOptions.ActiveAlways], owner: self, userInfo: nil)

        // keep track of where the mouse is within our text field
        self.setArea(trackingArea)

        if let ev = NSApp.currentEvent {
            if NSPointInRect(self.convertPoint(ev.locationInWindow, fromView: nil), self.bounds) {
                self.mouseIn = true
                myColorCursor?.set()
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
class TextField: NSTextField {
    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        addTrackingAreaIfNeeded()
        return super.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    override func mouseMoved(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseMoved(with: event)
        NSCursor.pointingHand.set()
    }
    private func addTrackingAreaIfNeeded() {
        if trackingAreas.isEmpty {
            let area = NSTrackingArea(rect: bounds, options: [.mouseEnteredAndExited, .activeAlways], owner: self, userInfo: nil)
            addTrackingArea(area)
        }
    }
}
```