# How to make NSTableView immediately display the IBeamCursor when hovering over a text cell?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

I'd like to make `NSTableView` behave more like a traditional text editor, where hovering over the editable text area immediately shows the `IBeamCursor` without having to click or double-click into the table cell first.

(I tried asking for a solution which changes the general behavior of the table view to achieve all of these things at once ([How to make an NSTableView behave more like a text editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76224315/how-to-make-an-nstableview-behave-more-like-a-text-editor)), but such a solution doesn't seem to exist.)

So the question is now, where would be an appropriate place to put the code to change the mouse cursor? Or maybe, is there a way forward the mouse events to the underlying text field / text cell so that the regular cursor behavior is triggered that occurs with a single `NSTextField` outside of an `NSTableView`?

I'd prefer a solution for a view-based table view (as I want to put a custom view into one of the table columns), but solutions for a cell-based table view are also appreciated if there is no easy way with view-based ones.

Comment: Have you tried adding a tracking area to the text field?

Comment: No. What would be the best place for adding that? Currently, the text field is created in IB.

Comment: A subclass of `NSTextField`.

Comment: While looking into how to add a tracking area to an `NSTextField` subclass, I stumbled about the following SO question, which I hadn't seen before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079531/cant-change-the-mouse-cursor-of-a-nstextfield The first answer solves my problem in a super easy way, without actually requiring to manually add a tracking area. So thanks for pointing me in the right direction! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out the answer is as simple as adding the following to an `NSTextField` subclass:

```
- (void)resetCursorRects {
    [self addCursorRect:[self bounds] cursor:[NSCursor IBeamCursor]];
}
```

Based on the following answer referring to a plain `NSTextField`, which happens to work for one embedded in a view-based `NSTableView` as well: [Can't change the mouse cursor of a NSTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079531/cant-change-the-mouse-cursor-of-a-nstextfield) (which I found through @Willeke's hint of subclassing the `NSTextField`)